# In Excel, how would I calculate the number of Mondays between dates that excludes a list of holidays?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I'm currently using this formula:

```
=INT((WEEKDAY(E2-2)-E2+E3)/7).
```

I know how to use the NETWORKDAYS function, which allows you to a specify a list of holiday dates, but I can't figure out how to specify a similar list using the formula above.

I'll also be using this for every day of the week once I figure the formula out.

Here's a screenshot of what I'm trying to do. The formula for the active cell is visible.

There aren't any holidays for Tuesdays, Wednesdays, and Thursdays, but there are some holidays falling on Mondays, Fridays, Saturdays and Sundays. I wrote them out below their respective weekday columns. I can't figure out how to integrate those dates into the formulas.

[image: excel number of meetings]

Answer (score 2):

This is for one year, but it can be extended.  Place your list of excluded dates in **G2** through **G10**.  In **H2** enter:

```
=IF(AND(TEXT(G2,"ddd")="Mon",G2>=E$2,G2<=E$3),1,"")
```

and copy down.  Then in **E4** enter:

```
=INT((WEEKDAY(E2-2)-E2+E3)/7)-SUM(H2:H10)
```

[image]

Change the size and contents of the table in cols **G** and **H** to suit your needs.